# Custom Magento product PHP copy imagepng not writing to folder

Tags: php, jquery, magento

Good afternoon. I was asked to help figure out why the product image is not showing up correctly in the cart once the custom seat is created. This code was inherited so I honestly don't fully understand how it works but I did want to try to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

You can see the code in action if you visit this [link](http://shop.enjoymfg.com/seat-covers-9/custom-seat-covers.html).

I have managed to locate the files that appear to run the page and they can be downloaded from this [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xyxdssocmr9qhuh/AABmjT_UCuiM75GCpWL82--da?dl=0).

## save-custom.phtml

```
$style = $_REQUEST['style'];
$ribs1 = $_REQUEST['ribs'];
$top1 = $_REQUEST['top'];
$side1 = $_REQUEST['side'];
$ribs1 = explode(Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB), $_REQUEST['ribs']);
$ribs = $ribs1[1];
$top1 = explode(Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB), $_REQUEST['top']);
$top = $top1[1];
$side1 = explode(Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB), $_REQUEST['side']);
$side = $side1[1];
//die($ribs ."   |  " .$ribs1[0]);
//$side = "black_sides.png";
//$top = "green_top.png";
$newCustomPhotoName = $_REQUEST['newPict'];

if ($style == 'ribbed') {
    $first = $top;
    $second = $ribs;
    $photo = imagecreatefrompng("$first");
    $frame = imagecreatefrompng("$second");
    $w = imagesx($photo);
    $h = imagesy($photo);

    imagealphablending($photo, true);
    imagesavealpha($photo, true);
    imagealphablending($frame, true);
    imagesavealpha($frame, true);

    imagecopy($photo, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
    imagepng($photo, $newCustomPhotoName);


    $photo = imagecreatefrompng("$newCustomPhotoName");
    $frame = imagecreatefrompng("$side");
    $w = imagesx($photo);
    $h = imagesy($photo);

    imagealphablending($photo, true);
    imagesavealpha($photo, true);
    imagealphablending($frame, true);
    imagesavealpha($frame, true);
    imagecopy($photo, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
    imagepng($photo, $newCustomPhotoName);
} else {
    $first = $side;
    $second = $top;
    $photo = imagecreatefrompng("$first");
    $frame = imagecreatefrompng("$second");
    $w = imagesx($photo);
    $h = imagesy($photo);

    imagealphablending($photo, true);
    imagesavealpha($photo, true);
    imagealphablending($frame, true);
    imagesavealpha($frame, true);

    imagecopy($photo, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
    imagepng($photo, $newCustomPhotoName);
}



//echo $newCustomPhotoName;
copy("$newCustomPhotoName", 'media/catalog/category/custom/' . $newCustomPhotoName);
unlink($newCustomPhotoName);
//$session->setData("CustomSeatCoverImage", 'catalog/category/custom/'.$newCustomPhotoName);
die($newCustomPhotoName);
```

Here is what I found today:
I added this code to save-custom-seats.php
The top code will create the folder and add the image into it

```
echo "$style\n\n";
echo "$top\n\n";
echo "$side\n\n";
//this works
$srcfile='http://shop.enjoymfg.com/media/catalog/category/file_5.jpg'; // image in another folder on the server
$dstfile='media/catalog/category/custom-test/test2.jpg'; // new destination as a test for writing 
mkdir(dirname($dstfile), 0755, true);
if (!copy($srcfile, $dstfile)) { // checks to see if the src copies to the new desination
    echo "failed to copy test...\n";
}

//this does not work
if (!copy("$newCustomPhotoName", 'media/catalog/category/custom-test/' . $newCustomPhotoName)) {
    echo "failed to copy $newCustomPhotoName...\n";
}
```

This is giving me an alert that says the image is failing to be copied into the directory. I'm going to keep looking but if anyone can give advice on a better way to write some sort of error check I would appreciate it. I'm not sure how to get more details on exactly why it's not writing to the directory.

I did check the permissions and the directory is writable.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the following:
 - The url has double slashes after media// as in `media//catalog/category/custom/ribbed_1517529293131.png`
 - Also the content type is text/html not image/png.
 - check that the image is actually created
 - and if so, see if the new image is readable with the correct file permissions
 - if image not created, also check you have the right permissions to write files, sorry the code is not very clear to follow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I added some stuff I found today to my question.